# How to download file using django as backend and nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-rest-framework, backend

I have a filefield in a document model from which i can upload files like this

```
document=models.FileField(max_length=350 ,validators=[FileExtensionValidator(extensions)])
```

uploading is working good, now i want to implement download feature for the frontend, but only those files which are uploaded by the user.

using url method is think less secure,

another way i saw is creating download function in the views,

and another i saw using nginx i can implement.

Kindly guide me which method is best, and what steps to take to implement the download feature, and will i need docker too if i am using nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found another way, there is a library which makes everything alot easier named as django_downloadview.

Here is the link to library https://pypi.org/project/django-downloadview/
and here is the link to documentations https://django-downloadview.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It solved the problem for me now for creating a download link with an id to download file from storage lets see what happens in the future.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).